# How does =~ behave in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following `perl` script:

```
$myVariable = "some value";
//... some code ...
$myVariable =~ s/\+/ /g;
$myVariable =~s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/seg;
//.. some more code ...
```

Reading from `perl` documentation, I think that `=~` operator returns a `boolean` value, namely `true` or `false`.

My question is: Does the above operations where `$myVariable` is involved affect its value, or not.

N.B. The `$myVariable`'s value is set in my script to a `string` that is a result from the `$_` variable's `split`. I think that should not affect the behavior of that operation.

P.S. If you need more code from my script just let me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$myVariable` is changed, but because you are doing substitutions (`s///`), not because the result of a match or substitution is a boolean; `=~` is not like `=`, it is like `==`.  If you want the boolean result of the action, you need to assign it.

```
$result = $myVariable =~ s/\+/ /g;
```

Answer (score 2):

We are talking about

```
leftvalue =~ rightvalue
```

rightvalue must be one of these things:

```
m/regexp/
s/regexp/replacement/
tr/regexp/translation/
```

leftvalue can be anything that is a left value.

The expresion `leftvalue =~ rightwalue` always evaluates to a boolean value, but this value is not assigned to leftvalue! This boolean value is the value of the expression itself! So you can use it very fine in an if-clause:

```
if (leftvalue =~ rightvalue) {
    // do something
}
```

- `m/regexp/` will never change anything. It just tests, if regexp matches on leftvalue.
- `s/regexp/replacement/` also tests if regexp matches on leftvalue, and if so, it replaces the matching part with `replacement`. If regexp did match, `leftvalue =~ rightvalue` is true, otherwise it is false.
- `tr/regexp/replacement/` analogously the same as `s///`, but with translation instead of replacement.

So this will work fine:

```
my @a=('acbc123','aubu123');
foreach (@a) {
    if ($_ =~ s/c(\d)/x$1/g;) {
        $_ .= 'MATCHED!';
    }
}
```

The results will be:

```
a[0] = 'acbx123MATCHED!'
```

the 'c', followed by a digit did match the regular expression. So ist was replaced by 'x' and that digit. And because it matched, the if-statement is true, and 'MATCHED!' is attached to the string.

```
a[1] = 'aubu123'
```

The regular expression did not match. Nothing was replaced and the if-statement was false.

Comment: "The expresion leftvalue =~ rightwalue always evaluates to a boolean value, but this value is not assigned to leftvalue!" is false. e.g. `my @matches = "abracadabra" =~ /(a)/g;` Even in scalar context, it can return something that's isn't boolean. e.g. `my $num_matches = $s =~ s/a/b/g;` e.g. `my $new = $old =~ s/a/b/gr;`

Answer (score 2):

The binding operator is just "binds" a target variable to one of the operators. It doesn't affect the value. The substitution operator, `s///`, normally changes the target value and returns the number of substitutions it made.

```
 my $count = $target =~ s/.../.../;
 my $count = ( $target =~ s/.../.../ );  # same thing, clarified with ()
```

Starting with Perl v5.14, there's a `/r` flag for the substitution operator that leaves alone the target value, and, instead of returning a count, returns the modified value:

```
 my $modified = $target =~ s/.../.../r;
```

Answer (score 1):

=~ doesn't quite mean anything by itself, it also needs something on its right to do to the variable on its left.

To see if a variable **matches** a pattern, you use m// on the right, you'll probably want to use this as a boolean, but you can also use it in other senses. This does not alter $foo:

```
$foo =~ m/pattern/
```

To **substitute** a replacement for a pattern, you use s/// on the right, this alters $foo:

```
$foo =~ s/pattern/replacement/;
```

To **translate** single characters within $foo, you use tr/// on the right, this alters $foo:

```
$foo =~ tr/abc/def/;
```